# Eclipse WTP / maven webapp not recognizing static resources

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, war

I created a new maven project in eclipse via the new project wizard, and using **maven-archetype-webapp**. I ran it in Tomcat and got the standard Hello World JSP, no problem.

I then added **fun.js** in **src/main/webapp**. I can access this via *localhost:8080/prj/fun.js*, no problem.

I then added a dependency to the requirejs webjar in the **pom.xml**. I also added this to **web.xml**:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/webjars/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The result is that I am able to access the webjar files via /prj/webjars/requirejs/...., but when I try to go to *localhost:8080/prj/fun.js*, I get a 404 error.

Why is my static resource no longer available?